# SUM() counts row twice and displaying double result

Tags: mysql

Why `SUM()` counts row twice and displaying double of actual result in here ?

Here I m trying to count total rows of `status` that has 0 value from the **inv_id** table of each student (`inv_id.s_id`) .

it has to show `4` based on the row number in **inv_lst** table but here it is showing `8`.

If `fee.id` is `GROUP_BY` then it shows actual SUM but same student id starts to duplicate.

**Please see fiddle** - [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0626fc/2)

Database Structure

**class**

```
id  |   ttl
===========
1   |   One
2   |   Two
```

**section**

```
id  |   ttl
===========
1   |   A
2   |   B
```

**fee**

```
id  |   ttl
===============
1   |   Annual
2   |   Monthly
```

**student**

```
id  |   ttl |   cls |   sec
===========================
1   |   John|   1   |   1
2   |   Paul|   1   |   1
3   |   Rina|   2   |   1
```

**sec_fee**

```
id  |   c_id|   s_id|   f_id|   fee
===================================
1   |   1   |   1   |   1   |   1000
2   |   2   |   1   |   2   |   560
```

**inv_id**

```
id  |   s_id|   ft_id   |   status
==================================
1   |   1   |   1       |   0
2   |   1   |   2       |   0
3   |   1   |   3       |   0
4   |   1   |   4       |   0
```

Mysql

```
    SELECT
        student.id, student.ttl AS stdt, 
        cls.ttl AS cls, 
        sec.ttl AS sec,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fee.id, '.', fee.ttl, '-', sec_fee.fee,'<br/>' ORDER BY sec_fee.f_id) AS amnt,
        SUM(inv_id.status=0) AS upad,
        SUM(inv_id.status=1) AS pad
    FROM
        student
    JOIN
        cls ON cls.id=student.cls
    LEFT JOIN
        sec ON sec.id=student.sec
    LEFT JOIN
        inv_id ON inv_id.s_id = student.id
    LEFT JOIN
        sec_fee ON sec_fee.c_id = student.cls
    LEFT JOIN
        fee ON fee.id = sec_fee.f_id
    WHERE
        cls.id = 1
```

Comment: Because of join with `inv_id` , `sec_fee` and then `fee` table you are getting multiple rows for each student

Comment: Check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0626fc/29